# It is possible to send the count(*) of all tables in a dataset to a csv file using bigquery API in python?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am trying to get the count and distinct count of data  of each table of each dataset of a given project using bigquery API in python and export the result to a csv file . the problem is only the count of the last table is sent to the csv file , need to get all the results into csv file . how to proceed with this ?(Note : the same was successfully executed in bigquery )

tried to try a function within the loop to return the result of the query and to add it but not successful, also tried to print the result of the query_job outside the loop that also failed .

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json
(r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\API.json ')
project = 'project_name'
def test_table_count(client): 

    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
    table = client.get_table(table_ref)      
    datasets = list(client.list_datasets()) 
    for dataset in datasets:       
        tables = list(client.list_tables(dataset=dataset.reference))
        print("Total_Table_Count ",len(tables))
        for t in tables:
            table_full_id = t.full_table_id
            tt=table_full_id.replace(':','.')
            t = tt.split('.')[2]
            d = tt.split('.')[1]
            query="Select '{}' Dataset, '{}' Table, count(*) Total_Count 
            FROM `{}`".format(d,t,tt)
            df = pd.read_gbq(query, project_id='pro_id',dialect=
            'standard',index_col=None, col_order=None, reauth=False, 
            verbose=True,private_key=None)
            if df.shape[0]==0:
            print('No records present in this dataset')
            else:
            print("df_content",df)
            export_csv = df.to_csv (r'C:\path\datset_count1.csv', index = 
            None, header=True,sep=',')
```

Expected :a csv file with dataset_name, tabe_name, count(*) of each table.
Actual : daatset_name , table_name and count(*) from the last table of the last dataset in the given project.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is just that you're overwriting the csv file each time. If you want to append the results you have to add `mode = 'a'` in `df.to_csv` options:

```
export_csv = df.to_csv (r'C:\path\datset_count1.csv', index = 
            None, header = True, mode = 'a', sep = ',')
```

Keep in mind that this will print the headers for each table so you might want to set `header = False` or, even better, just print them the first time. For example, you can add this line at the start of the script:

```
is_first = True
```

and then when writing inside the `for` loop:

```
export_csv = df.to_csv (r'C:\path\datset_count1.csv', index = 
                None, header = is_first, mode = 'a', sep = ',')
is_first = False
```

The `header` option will be set according to the value of `is_first`, which will only be `True` for the first item.

Result:

```
$ cat datset_count1.csv
Dataset,Table,Total_Count
dataset1,table1,12967
dataset1,table2,50
dataset1,table3,102
...
```